# A Map with a differently type-parametrised value types

Tags: scala, generics, dictionary, type-parameter

I want to know if it is possible to create a map with values of different constructed types. Like this:

```
class WowClass[A <: HeyClass]

val map = Map[String, WowClass[A <: HeyClass]]()
```

so that the values can be different children of the `HeyClass`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely store subtypes of a declared value type `V` in a map, but if you read from the map, all you know is that you get values of type `V`, i.e., the upper type bound of your hierarchy. You could then pattern match on the values if you need to know more.

```
trait V
case class A1() extends V
case class A2() extends V

var map = Map[String, V]()

map += ("A1" -> A1())
map += ("A2" -> A2())

map.values.head match {
  case a1: A1 => println("A1")
  case a2: A2 => println("A2")
}
```

If that is not precise enough for your, have a look at [HLists](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/type-level-programming-in-scala-part-6a-heterogeneous-list%C2%A0basics/). They are, in a sense, a type-safe implementation of n-tuples, i.e., a map of fixed size with natural number keys and values of arbitrary types.

Viewing a (read-only) `Map[K, V]` as a function `K -> V` could help to understand why it is not directly possible to have a map that takes values of different types, and that also statically knows the exact type of the values returned for each key. Given the above function signature, how should it be possible to statically know that key `"foo"` returns a value of `V1 <: V`, whereas key `"bar"` returns a value of type `V2 <: V`? This additional information somehow would need to be part of the function signature, which it actually is in the case of HLists.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Really, Maps can be seen as functions.. that explains much.. Actually, I would join the answer of Chris to yours one and mark it as teh answer since it would explain the reason and propose a ready-to-use solution and that could benefit for future references.. hmm SO does not allow merging posts ) sometimes I miss that ))

Answer (score 1):

Miles Sabins [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/) will get the exact type back out if using HLists or HMaps.  Could be worth a quick look at the examples to see if they are the right direction for you or not.

Comment: Wow, I have looked at Shapeless.. I am confused... It looks very very powerful, and I understand the examples and explanations written there and how that works, I like it and I would like to use the power someday, but.. are there any examples of usecases? I just can't think of anything like that.. surely because I am coming to FP from OOP.

Comment: Lenses are, I think, the easiest to explain use cases for.  If we try to change the nested immutable address in his example by hand (or even using copy) its doable, but not pleasant.  Now nest it several levels further down and the pain is obvious, and the big win from lenses is clearer.

Comment: The newtype approach is also called tagging in some Scala libraries - it basically allows you to restrict operations and access on a "type", the compiler enforces this but actually its another type internally, so as an e.g. restrict a range on an int by enforcing via a newtype but not allocating a wrapper.